# Wireguard - Unable to access web server behind firewall

Tags: vpn, tunnel, wireguard

I have a server A with WG tunnel IP 10.9.0.1 , server B with WG tunnel IP 10.9.0.4 and my mobile with WG tunnel IP 10.9.0.3.

Server A and B has UFW enabled and allowed incoming ports as SSH and WG port.

I will connect to Server A via my mobile for all my internet activities which works fine. I am trying to access a web server running on Server B on my mobile browser via http://10.9.0.4 and unable to get it to work when UFW on Server B is enabled. However, when I disable UFW on Server B, I am able to access the web server via my mobile. I want the web server to be accessed only on VPN and dont want public access. Can someone please help in finding what rule is missing in UFW that is blocking my access to Server B's web server? I have tried accepting all incoming/outgoing on interface wg0 on Server B but in vain.

Server B and mobile are connected as peers to Server A.I am able to ping Server B from mobile and Server A.

UFW for Server B

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5440                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
44787/udp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80,443/tcp on wg0          ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
5440 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
44787/udp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80,443/tcp (v6) on wg0     ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             

443                        ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
53                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
443 (v6)                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
53 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

UFW for Server A

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5440                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
44787                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
44787 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             

53                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
80,443/tcp                 ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on wg0           
53/udp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on wg0           
53 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
80,443/tcp (v6)            ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on wg0      
53/udp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on wg0
```

Edit: i have disabled UFW on Server B and replaced with iptables as below.Problem exists.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#############################
#  SETUP
#############################

# Define your hostname
DEMOSTHENES=X.X.X.X

# Clear all rules
/sbin/iptables -F

iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.9.0.0/24 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT #sample rule to allow packet forwarding from your wg subnet


#############################
#  MANAGEMENT RULES
#############################

# Allow SSH (alternate port)
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d $DEMOSTHENES --dport 5440 -j ACCEPT 

/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d $DEMOSTHENES --dport 44787 -j ACCEPT 
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p udp -d $DEMOSTHENES --dport 44787 -j ACCEPT 

# Allow web server access
iptables -A INPUT -i wg0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wg0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 80,443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -j DROP 

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             v8.domain.co          tcp dpt:5440
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             v8.domain.co          tcp dpt:44787
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             v8.domain.co          udp dpt:44787
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https state NEW,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  10.9.0.0/24          anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport sports http,https state ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question  and post your firewall rules as text.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used ufw before but i see that it says your 'routed' policy is set to deny on server B ufw rules, meaning all the packets coming in from a different host that are destined to end on server B are being blocked (if I understand correctly). Try either creating a rule to allow forwarding packets (also edit /etc/sysctl.conf and make sure you are forwarding ipv4 and ipv6 packets; net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 and net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1) or set the default policy for the FORWARD chain to accept and see what happens. I use iptables and its very finicky, sometimes using Insert instead of Append for a rule makes all the difference.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.9.0.0/24 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT #sample rule to allow packet forwarding from your wg subnet
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT #change default policy on filter tables FORWARD chain
```

Comment: I have updated thread with new iptables rules. Still doesn't work.